# can not understand this SEGFAULT

Tags: c++, linux, segmentation-fault, g++

I am programming a c/c++ SDL synth which works on linux, windows, and handled psp and I mix c/c++ in multiple part of the code.
I use new/malloc and I don't think I mix them up but if I do please tell me where and why.

My main program is now near 20 000 line and it works fine.
But I allways fall into a bug when I began to modify it and I can not understand and spot my real error.

I fall into SIGSEV when I began to modify some part of my code and it take me hours to make it work without understand why I fall into this.
And after some modification it works again, and I have no clue about why I have a SIGSEV and why it is fixed now and how I can have modify it to make it works and prevent future mistake.
So I ask you to explain it what is my real error.

Here is a gdb log with a really strip down version and the kind of crash I have :

```
    yoyz@yoyz-laptop:~/build/audio/picoloop/tmp/ gdb ./WaveTable 
    GNU gdb (GDB) 7.4.1-debian
    Copyright (C) 2012 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
    License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later         <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
    This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
    There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show         copying"
    and "show warranty" for details.
    This GDB was configured as "x86_64-linux-gnu".
    For bug reporting instructions, please see:
    <http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>...
    Reading symbols from         /home/yoyz/build/audio/picoloop/tmp/WaveTable...done.
    (gdb) r
    Starting program: /home/yoyz/build/audio/picoloop/tmp/WaveTable 
    warning: the debug information found in "/lib64/ld-2.13.so" does not         match "/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2" (CRC mismatch).

    Generator::init() Allocating memory
    Generator::one() 0x00604010
    Generator::sine() 0x00604010
    Generator::saw() 0x00604010
    Generator::pulse() 0x00604010

    Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
    _int_malloc (av=0x7ffff7639e40, bytes=32768) at malloc.c:4738
    4738    malloc.c: No such file or directory.
    (gdb)
```

Here is the strip down version of the code :

```
    #include "MyMaster.h"
    #include "Generator.h"
    #include "WaveTable.h"
    #include "WaveTableManager.h"


    int main(int argc,char **argv)
    {
      Generator G;
      WaveTableManager & WTM = WaveTableManager::getInstance();
      WaveTable* WT;

      G.init();


      WT = new WaveTable();
      WT->setSize(WAVETABLE_SIZE);
      G.one();
      memcpy(WT->getBuffer(),G.getBuffer(),WAVETABLE_SIZE*DEFAULTBITRATE/8);
      WTM.insert(WT,PICO_WAVETABLE_ONE);


      WT = new WaveTable();
      WT->setSize(WAVETABLE_SIZE);
      G.sine();
      memcpy(WT->getBuffer(),G.getBuffer(),WAVETABLE_SIZE*DEFAULTBITRATE/8);
      WTM.insert(WT,PICO_WAVETABLE_SINE);



      WT = new WaveTable();
      WT->setSize(WAVETABLE_SIZE);
      G.saw();
      memcpy(WT->getBuffer(),G.getBuffer(),WAVETABLE_SIZE*DEFAULTBITRATE/8);
      WTM.insert(WT,PICO_WAVETABLE_SAW);


      WT = new WaveTable();
      WT->setSize(WAVETABLE_SIZE);
      G.pulse();
      memcpy(WT->getBuffer(),G.getBuffer(),WAVETABLE_SIZE*DEFAULTBITRATE/8);
      WTM.insert(WT,PICO_WAVETABLE_PULSE);


      WT = new WaveTable();
      WT->setSize(WAVETABLE_SIZE);
      G.triangle();
      memcpy(WT->getBuffer(),G.getBuffer(),WAVETABLE_SIZE*DEFAULTBITRATE/8);
      WTM.insert(WT,PICO_WAVETABLE_TRGL);


      WT = new WaveTable();
      WT->setSize(WAVETABLE_SIZE);
      G.noise();
      memcpy(WT->getBuffer(),G.getBuffer(),WAVETABLE_SIZE*DEFAULTBITRATE/8);
      WTM.insert(WT,PICO_WAVETABLE_NOISE);


      printf("wavetablemanager.getSize : %d\n",WTM.getSize());

    }
```

MyMaster.h

```
    #ifndef __MASTER____
    #define __MASTER____
    #include <SDL/SDL.h>
    #define WAVETABLE_SIZE  1024*16
    #define DEFAULTBITRATE   16

    enum 
      {
        PICO_WAVETABLE_SINE,
        PICO_WAVETABLE_SAW,
        PICO_WAVETABLE_PULSE,
        PICO_WAVETABLE_TRGL,
        PICO_WAVETABLE_NOISE,
        PICO_WAVETABLE_ONE,
        PICO_WAVETABLE_SIZE
      };

    #endif
```

Generator.h

```
    using namespace std;

    #include <SDL/SDL_types.h>
    #include <math.h>
    #include "MyMaster.h"

    #ifndef __GENERATOR__
    #define __GENERATOR__

    class Generator 
    {
    public:
      Generator();
      ~Generator();
      void init();
      void sine();
      void saw();
      void pulse();
      void triangle();
      void noise();
      void one();
      Sint16 * getBuffer();

     private:
      Sint16 * table;
      int      table_size;
      int      index;
      int      d;

    };
    #endif
```

Generator.cpp

```
    #include "Generator.h"

    Generator::Generator()
    {
      table_size=WAVETABLE_SIZE;
    }

    Generator::~Generator()
    {
    }

    void Generator::init()
    {
      if (table_size>0)
        {
          printf("Generator::init() Allocating memory\n");
          table=(Sint16*)malloc(sizeof(Sint16)*table_size);
          if (table==0)
            {
              printf("Error allocating memory\n");
              //return 0;
            } 
        }   
    }   

    void Generator::sine()
    {
      int i;
      float f;
      Sint16 s;
      Sint16 bitdepth=16-1;
      printf("Generator::sine() 0x%08.8X\n",table);
      for (i=0;i<table_size;i++)
        {
          s=sin((2*3.14159*i*1)/table_size)*(1<<bitdepth-2);
          table[i]=s;
          //printf("table[%d]=%d\n",i,s);
        }
    }

    void Generator::saw()
    {
      int i;
      float f;
      Sint16 s;
      Sint16 bitdepth=16;
      Sint16 dec;

      printf("Generator::saw() 0x%08.8X\n",table);

      s=(1<<(bitdepth-2));
      dec=(1<<(bitdepth-2))/(table_size/2);

      for (i=0;i<table_size;i++)
        {
          table[i]=s;
          s=s-dec;
        }
    }

    void Generator::pulse()
    {
      int i;
      float f;
      Sint16 s;
      Sint16 bitdepth=16;
      Sint16 dec=(1<<(bitdepth-2))/(table_size/2);

      printf("Generator::pulse() 0x%08.8X\n",table);

      for (i=0;i<table_size/2;i++)
        {
          table[i]=((1<<(bitdepth-2))/2);
        }
      for (i=table_size/2;i<table_size;i++)
        {
          table[i]=((1<<(bitdepth-2))*-1)/2;
        }
    }

    void Generator::triangle()
    {
      int i;
      float f;
      Sint16 s=0;
      Sint16 bitdepth=16;
      Sint16 dec=(1<<(bitdepth-2))/(table_size/4);

      printf("Generator::triangle() 0x%08.8X\n",table);

      //table=(Sint16*)malloc(sizeof(Sint16)*table_size);
      for (i=0;i<(table_size*1)/4;i++)
        {
          table[i]=s;
          s=s+dec;
        }
      for (i=(table_size*1)/4;i<(table_size*3)/4;i++)
        {
          table[i]=s;
          s=s-dec;
        }
      for (i=(table_size*3)/4;i<table_size;i++)  
        {
          table[i]=s;
          s=s+dec;
        }
    }


    void Generator::noise()
    {
      int i;
      float f;
      Sint16 s;
      Sint16 bitdepth=16;

      printf("Generator::noise() 0x%08.8X\n",table);

      srand(1<<(bitdepth-2));
      for (i=0;i<table_size;i++)
        {
          if (rand()%2==0)
            table[i]=rand()%8192;
          else
            table[i]=(rand()%8192)*-1;
        }
    }

    void Generator::one()
    {
      int i;
      float f;
      Sint16 s;
      Sint16 bitdepth=16;

      printf("Generator::one() 0x%08.8X\n",table);

      for (i=0;i<table_size;i++)
        {
          table[i]=1<<bitdepth-1;
        }
    }



    Sint16 * Generator::getBuffer()
    {
      return table;
    }
```

WaveTable.h

```
    #include "MyMaster.h"
    #include <SDL/SDL_types.h>
    #ifndef __WAVETABLE__
    #define __WAVETABLE__

    class WaveTable
    {
     public:
      WaveTable();
      ~WaveTable();

       int      setSize(int bufferSize); 
       int      allocMemory();
       int      freeMemory(); 


      Sint16 * getBuffer();
      char   * getName();
      Sint32   getSize();



     private:
      Sint32   size;
      Sint16 * buffer;
      char   * name;

    };

    #endif
```

WaveTable.cpp

```
    #include "WaveTable.h"
    using namespace std;

    WaveTable::WaveTable()
    {
      size=0;
      buffer=0;
      name=0;
    }

    WaveTable::~WaveTable()
    {
    }


    int WaveTable::allocMemory()
    {
      if (size>0)
        {
          buffer=(Sint16*)malloc(sizeof(Sint16)*size);
          if (buffer==0)
            {
              printf("Error allocating memory\n");
              return 0;
            }
        }
      return size;
    }


    int WaveTable::freeMemory()
    {
      if (buffer!=0)
        {
          free(buffer);
          buffer=0;
        }
    }

    int WaveTable::setSize(int bufferSize)
    {
      if (bufferSize>=0)
        size=bufferSize;

      if (buffer!=0)
        this->freeMemory();
      return this->allocMemory();
    }

    Sint16 * WaveTable::getBuffer()
    {
      return buffer;
    }
```

WaveTableManager.h

```
    using namespace std;

    #include <vector>
    #include "WaveTable.h"

    #ifndef __WAVETABLEMANAGER__
    #define __WAVETABLEMANAGER__

    class WaveTableManager 
    {
    private:

      WaveTableManager();
      ~WaveTableManager();

      vector<WaveTable*> wtvector;  

      int    size;


    public:
      static WaveTableManager& getInstance();

      int         getSize();
      void        insert(WaveTable * WT,int position);
      WaveTable * get(int position);


    };
    #endif
```

WaveTableManager.cpp

```
    #include "WaveTableManager.h"

    WaveTableManager::WaveTableManager() : wtvector()
    {
      size=0;
    }


    WaveTableManager::~WaveTableManager()
    {

    }



    WaveTableManager& WaveTableManager::getInstance()
    {
      static WaveTableManager instance;
      return instance;
    }


    int WaveTableManager::getSize()
    {
      return wtvector.size();
    }

    void WaveTableManager::insert(WaveTable * WT,int position)
    {
      if (wtvector.size()<=position)
        wtvector.resize(position);
      wtvector[position]=WT;
    }


    WaveTable * WaveTableManager::get(int position)
    {
      return wtvector[position];
    }
```

Makefile.WaveTable

```
    CC=g++

    CFLAGS=-O0 -DLINUX -D__RTAUDIO__ -DLINUX_DESKTOP -I. -LSDL/lib -g -fpermissive
    SOURCES=WaveTableTest.cpp WaveTable.cpp WaveTableManager.cpp Generator.cpp
    OBJECTS=$(SOURCES:.cpp=.o)
    EXECUTABLE=WaveTable

    all: $(SOURCES) $(EXECUTABLE)

    $(EXECUTABLE): $(OBJECTS)
            $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) $(OBJECTS) -o $@

    .cpp.o:
            $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@

    clean:
            -rm -f $(OBJECTS) $(EXECUTABLE)
```

Comment: It's difficult to believe that you can't produce a smaller program that causes this problem.

Comment: You'd get useful answers if you removed all the code and described the problem generally (code with lots of `malloc`/`free` functions segfaulting in `malloc`) and asked for general tips about how to troubleshoot. (Hint, `valgrind`.)

Comment: `I use new/malloc and I don't think I mix them up but if I do please tell me where and why.`  My question is just "why?"

Comment: `My main program is now near 20 000 line and it works fine.`  Then why the problem?  `But I allways fall into a bug when I began to modify it` which means that there could have been an existing bug in the program you claim is "working fine".

Comment: @Drew  : I may be able to produce it on less line but 400 line is readable

Comment: @Paul : because sometime it is difficult to not mix them up, when you include some other c++ and c file

Comment: @yoyz2k *" I may be able to produce it on less"*  Please produce it on less, then.  We are doing far more than just reading it.

Comment: @yoyz2k `buffer=(Sint16*)malloc(sizeof(Sint16)*size);`  You're purposefully mixing C and C++ for no reason here.  The code is in a class function, so the `C` language has no bearing here.  You could have simply used `vector<Sint16>` instead of this.

Comment: @yoyz2k - Except for the issue I pointed out in my answer, your `WaveTable` class needs no pointers whatsoever from the looks of it.  Replace those `char*` with `std::string`, replace `Sint16* buffer` with `std::vector<Sint16> buffer`, and you have a class that is much safer , less code, and more stable than what you have now.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie You are right, and thank you, I will replace my C code with c++ one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one issue:

```
void WaveTableManager::insert(WaveTable * WT,int position)
{
  if (wtvector.size()<=position)
    wtvector.resize(position);
  wtvector[position]=WT;  // < -- Out of bounds access
}
```

When you call `resize()`, the upper bound is `vector::size()-1`.  Since `position` is the new size of the vector, what you probably want is this:

```
  wtvector[position - 1] = WT;
```

Comment: That's a great find, although rewarding lazy questions like this may have a bad ripple effect for SO.

Comment: @DrewDormann That's the risk of putting in too much work I guess.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Thank you you spotted it in no time !!!

Comment: I can't... It's my first post on StackOverflow. And I need a reputation of 15 to up this reply. I'd like to thank you for your post.